# Is "Snow White with Red Hair" manga available in color?

Tags: snow-white-with-the-red-hair

Is *Snow White with the Red Hair* manga available in colour? Or is it only in black and white?

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem any colored version of *Snow White with Red Hair* manga.

The list of the published **printed** manga on [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%B5%A4%E9%AB%AA%E3%81%AE%E7%99%BD%E9%9B%AA%E5%A7%AB#%E6%9B%B8%E8%AA%8C%E6%83%85%E5%A0%B1) only listed 1 series, which doesn't seem to be in color (just a normal black & white).

Googling [赤髪の白雪姫 漫画 カラー版](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E8%B5%A4%E9%AB%AA%E3%81%AE%E7%99%BD%E9%9B%AA%E5%A7%AB+%E6%BC%AB%E7%94%BB+%E3%82%AB%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E7%89%88) (*Akagami no Shirayukihime manga COLOR ban*, "Snow White with Red Hair" manga colored version) also didn't give any convincing proof whether there's a colored version of the manga either.

Searching on [eBookJapan (Japanese)](https://www.ebookjapan.jp/ebj/search_book/?q=%E8%B5%A4%E9%AB%AA%E3%81%AE%E7%99%BD%E9%9B%AA%E5%A7%AB) also didn't list any **digitally** colored version.